# Deleted element is there after deletion until refresh - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, axios

I am trying to create a simple application where I have a list of providers and wanna add/delete them... the same issue is for both cases

when I try to delete or element and when I try to add an element (provider)

Here is the situation:

**Provider.vue**: * loading providers from and API (simple as that)

```
<template lang="html">
 <div class="container">
   <h1 class="h2">{{ $t('default.titles.providers') }}</h1>
     <button class="btn btn-success my-3 float-right" @click="addProvider">{{ $t('default.buttons.add') }}</button>
     <template v-if="showError">
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
       <tw-loading-error :message="this.error"></tw-loading-error>
     </template>
     <template v-else>
       <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col">#</th>
             <th scope="col">{{ $t('default.provider.name') }}</th>
             <th scope="col"></th>
             <th scope="col"></th>
             <th scope="col"></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <tr v-for="(provider, index) in providerList" :key="index">
             <th scope="row">{{index+1}}</th>
             <td>{{provider.provider_name}}</td>
             <td :title="$t('default.buttons.edit')">
               <router-link :to="{ name: 'edit-provider', params: { provider } }">
                 <Edit2Icon
                   class="pointer">
                 </Edit2Icon>
              </router-link>
             </td>
             <td :title="$t('default.buttons.delete')">
               <router-link class="delete" :to="{ name: 'delete-provider', params: { provider } }">
                   <DeleteIcon
                     class="pointer">
                   </DeleteIcon>
               </router-link>
             </td>
             <td :title="$t('default.buttons.add-client')">
               <router-link class="edit" :to="{ name: 'add-provider-user',
                                                params: {
                                                  provider_id: provider.id_provider,
                                                  provider_name: provider.provider_name
                                               }}">
                 <UserPlusIcon class="pointer"></UserPlusIcon>
               </router-link>
             </td>
           </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </template>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ProviderService from './../../../services/provider.service'
  import { Edit2Icon, DeleteIcon, UserPlusIcon } from 'vue-feather-icons'
  import LoadingError from './../../shared/alerts/LoadingError.vue'

  export default {
    name: "Provider",
    data() {
      return {
        providerList: [],
        error: '501: cannot load the providers :(',
        showError: false
      }
    },
    components: {
      'tw-loading-error': LoadingError,
      Edit2Icon, DeleteIcon, UserPlusIcon
    },
    methods: {
      getProviders() {
        ProviderService.getProviders().then(
          response => {
            this.providerList = response.data
          },
          error => {
            this.showError = true
            this.error = error
          }
        )
      },
      addProvider() {
        this.$router.push({name: "add-provider"})
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getProviders();
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.delete {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

**provider.service.js**: * very straightforward .. I either get all provider or delete a provider

```
import axios from '../axios/axios-conf'
import authHeader from './auth-header';

class ProviderService {
  async getProviders() {
    const response = await axios.get('/providers', { headers: authHeader() })
    return response
  }

  async deleteProvider(id){
     try {
       return await axios.delete('/provider/delete/'+id)
     } catch (error) {
       return error
     }
  }
}

 export default new ProviderService()
```

**DeleteProvider.vue**: * here is the culprit

```
<template lang="html">
 <div class="container">
   <h1 class="h2">{{$t('default.titles.delete')}} {{provider.name}}?</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteProvider(provider.id)">{{$t('default.buttons.yes')}}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" @click="goBack">{{$t('default.buttons.no')}}</button>
      </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
//  import axios from './../../../axios/axios-conf'
  import ProviderService from './../../../services/provider.service'

  export default {
    name: "DeleteProvider",
    data() {
      return {
        provider: {
          id: null,
          name: null
        }
      }
    },
    components: {
    },
    methods: {
      async deleteProvider(id){
        let c = confirm("Do you really want to delete it? You will not be able to restore this data again!")
        if(c){
          this.delete(id)
              .then(success => {
                return success
              })
              .catch(error => {
                return error
              })
          this.goBack()
        }
      },
      async delete(id){
        let response = await ProviderService.deleteProvider(id)
        return response
      },
      checkParams(){
          if(JSON.stringify(this.$route.params) === '{}'){
            this.goBack()
          }
      },
      goBack(){
        this.$router.push({ name: 'provider'})
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.provider.name = this.$route.params.provider.provider_name
      this.provider.id = this.$route.params.provider.id_provider
    },
    created() {
      this.checkParams()
    }
  }
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.pointer{
  cursor: pointer
}
</style>
```

the APIs work flawlessly .. they do what is expected.. the problem occurs, when I try to delete a provider VueJS redirects me (the router) so fast to the list of providers that the element does not disappear (the one deleted). Only after I refresh the page (either via F5 or going to another page and back to render it again) it is projected.

So the fact is, it is successfully deleted but the page does not wait or the deletion to project it right away.

What am I doing wrong? I do have async/await in my code for all functions (desperate situation calls for desperate measures :D )

PS: worth mentioning: it is happening only every now and then .. sometimes it works ok (so the element is not shown .. sometimes I have to refresh the page)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The `this.goBack()` isn't properly waiting for the async function to finish. The `this.delete(id)` line below and the `this.goBack()` lines are executed in parallel as the `delete` is an async call.

Also on a side note, you can also use a `try...catch` block instead of using the promise chaining. Look at my changes below:

```
async deleteProvider(id){
        let c = confirm("Do you really want to delete it? You will not be able to restore this data again!")
        if(c){
          try{
             const success = await this.delete(id)
             return success;
           } catch(error){
             return error;
           } finally {
              this.goBack(); // If you want to go back only on success, move this line inside the try block before the `return`.
           }
        }
      }
```